# How to validate presence in Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Ecto can validate format, inclusion, uniqueness and so on, but I can't see how I can validate presence? is there a method to add an error to a field if it's empty? Like `validates_presence_of` in RoR ? I can make it manually, it's not a problem, but I wonder if there is an already existing method for it like `validate_presence\3` or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the **required_fields** annotator in the model.

```
@required_fields ~w(name email)
```

For a Customer model with a total of 4 fields and 2 required fields like this:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Customer do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :model

  schema "customers" do
    field :name, :string
    field :email, :string
    field :bio, :string
    field :number_of_pets, :integer

    timestamps
  end

  @required_fields ~w(name email)
  @optional_fields ~w()

  def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  end
end
```

Phoenix will automatically validate the presence of the required fields and display error messages at the top of the form like below:

[image]

Comment: How can I change the custom error message? If I want to show "blah blah" instead of "can't be blank" ...

Comment: well, that would be a separate question!

Comment: well, let's make a separate question then ! There you go -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032246/how-to-add-a-custom-error-message-for-a-required-field

Comment: even though it appears to be the way, it doesn't work in my case for some reason, it doesn't add errors to the attributes

Comment: @JustMichael check if you are using the latest version of phoenix_ecto package

Comment: You were right, I was using some old one after all, I've updated it and it broke a few things, so I'll reply when I fix those, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

### `validate_required/3`

I can't say how it was in 2015 but for some good time now there's the [validate_required/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_required/3) function, which serves as an equivalent of "presence" validation in Rails. This function:

> Validates that one or more fields are present in the changeset [...]