# How to add a custom error message for a required field in Phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How can I change the error message for required fields? If I have something like that

```
@required_fields ~w(name email)
```

and I want to show "no way it's empty" instead of the default value of "can't be blank" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"can't be blank"` error message is hardcoded into Ecto at the moment. However, you can replace this error message by doing:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
  model
  |> cast(params, @required_fields, @optional_fields)
  |> required_error_messages("no way it's empty")
end

def required_error_messages(changeset, new_error_message) do
  update_in changeset.errors, &Enum.map(&1, fn
    {key, "can't be blank"} -> {key, new_error_message}
    {_key, _error} = tuple  -> tuple
  end)
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's too bad that it's hardcoded :( Most of the people will probably like to change it

Comment: You're right. Went ahead and added an issue to Ecto https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/issues/884 so they add a way to support it.

Comment: For now this is the way to go until the I18n system is working.

Comment: There's a missing ")" after Enum.map. I couldn't edit it myself as it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: Any concerns about using "def translate_error({msg, opts})" in generated  ErrorHelpers to match on phrase and push out an own key/message ?

Comment: Here with Ecto ~> 2.1, It's a bit different.

        ```update_in changeset.errors, &Enum.map(&1, fn
          {key, {"can't be blank", validations}} -> {key, {new_error_message, validations}}
          {_key, _error} = tuple  -> tuple
        end)```

Answer (score 10):

I normally customize this way:

```
validate_required(changeset, [:email], message: "Email cannot be blank.")
```

Comment: It wasn't possible back in the day. Now that's the way to go.

Comment: this wouldn't work, the error message would come out as `email Email cannot be blank`. You are only able to change the ending and it always adds the field name on the front (and in lowercase).

Answer (score 1):

I think `Ecto.Changeset` may have changed since the last answer was posted.  As of `ecto_sql` 3.1, the `%Ecto.Changeset{}` struct stores errors like this:

```
errors: [address1: {"can't be blank", [validation: :required]}]
```

So I had to alter the structure of the previous solution a bit. In this example, I am using [cast/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast/4) to cast a raw map (the first argument may be a changeset or a data tuple as `{data, types}`):

```
@permitted [:name, :phone, :url]
@parameter_types %{name: :string, phone: :string, url: :string}

def signup_changeset(params) do
    IO.inspect params
    cast({%{}, @parameter_types}, params, @permitted)
    |> validate_required([:name, :phone, :url])
    |> required_error_messages("no way it's empty")
end

defp required_error_messages(changeset, new_error_message) do
    update_in changeset.errors, &Enum.map(&1, fn
      {key, {"can't be blank", rules}} -> {key, {new_error_message, rules}}
      tuple  -> tuple
    end)
end
```

Note that you have to call `validate_required` before you will have any default "can't be blank" strings.

Alternatively, you can verbosely set an error message for each field in violation:

```
@permitted [:name, :phone, :url]
@parameter_types %{name: :string, phone: :string, url: :string}

def signup_changeset(params) do
    cast({%{}, @parameter_types}, params, @permitted)
    |> validate_required(:name, message: "Dude. You need an address.")
    |> validate_required(:phone, message: "You must have a name.")
    |> validate_required(:url, message: "We need a valid URL for your homepage.")
  end
```